AppLovin Max build error with Unity 6 Preview
[SafeDK-ERROR] Android variants not detected.
Please make sure you place the directive:
apply plugin: 'applovin'
after you apply the Android plugin in your build.gradle file
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':unityLibrary'.


Plugin with id 'applovin' not found.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.


Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
Android variants not detected.
Please make sure you place the directive:
apply plugin: 'applovin'
after you apply the Android plugin in your build.gradle file


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 3s
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:219)
